# How can I find out which intent a service (not in my app) is started by?

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent

I want to find out how Google Maps service is automatically started.

When I dump logcat of main buffer or events buffer, I can only find out which component of Google Maps is started, but no clues about **"Who"** (package) started it, and **"How"** (intent)?

Is there any debugging method that can be used to find them out?

Comment: Is modify firmware acceptable?

Comment: @JermaineXu I'm afraid not, I need to collect this information from my user as issue report. Root and ADB is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find "How", but still find no clue about "Who".

### "How"

Run `dumpsys activity services`, see the `intent` field:

```
* ServiceRecord{41526f40 u0 com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService}

  intent={act=com.google.android.location.internal.GMM_NLP}

  packageName=com.google.android.apps.maps
```

Comment: That is because `com.google.android.location.internal.GMM_NLP` is a service action, not a broadcast action, based on your `adb shell dumpsys activity services` output.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, my mistake. I corrected the answer. Could you give me any hint on monitoring "who" launched the given service?

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible, unless perhaps it's logged in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the solution to your problems

```
String uri = "geo:" + 0 + "," + 0 + "?q=" + address;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not related to my question. The service is not started by me, but some app which I don't know but I wanted to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActivityManager as an hack to get it. Something like:

```
ActivityManager aManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskList = aManager.getRecentTasks(1, 0);
Intent caller = recentTaskList.get(0).baseIntent;
```

I'm skipping validations here, but this should get you started.

Don't forget `GET_TASKS` permission.

Comment: This way, you can find out what app is **launched by** the intent. But what I need to figure out it what app **launches** the intent.